# How to make html table scrollbar supported in chrome browser?

Tags: html, css

I need your help. I have an HTML table that have many columns. I already made the horizontal scrollbar that fit the table and laptop screen using css and it was supported in firefox, and what I want to know why is my css scrollbar coding aren't supported in chrome browser?

this is my css

```
table.scroll {
table-layout: fixed;
display: block;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

and this the example of my html code (this is just the example because I have about more than 15 columns in my table

```
<table class="scroll">
<tr>
<td>aaaaaaa</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for your help... (I need to know this because some people who would use my html table are using chrome browser)

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to make sure you're closing your `<tr></tr>` tags properly.

The horizontal scroll bar does work with chrome, BUT you must set a table width, so that when your data overflows the x-axis you have something to scroll.

Let me illustrate:

HTML:

```
<table class="scroll">
<tr>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
   <td>aaaaaaa</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
  table.scroll {
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    max-width: 100px;
  }
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/vNVaMM)

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, I already tried it like you said but it's still doesn't work!!! and I'm getting confused, in firefox my table are fine, but in chrome it display the long table without scrollbar.

Comment: Well I don't know what's wrong I use chrome and it works fine for me.

Comment: do I need to add extension to my chrome? maybe an extension that would support the scrollbar?

Comment: There should be no need for that. All browsers support that attribute , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x you can try adding `-webkit-` as a prefix though and see if that helps